# Android Studio does not show project files and directories

Tags: android-studio

When I try to Open project from `File-> Open` a popup window open but its not showing any path inside nor showing any directory structure

Whenever I open a project from recent Projects android studio shows error

Event log shows:

> Do not call synchronous refresh under read lock (except from EDT) - this will cause a deadlock if there are any events to fire.

and after indexing done project tab is not showing any file or directory of the project.

Error Log :

```
ERROR - pi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl - Do not call synchronous refresh under read lock (except from EDT) - this will cause a deadlock if there are any events to fire. 
java.lang.Throwable at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl.execute(RefreshQueueImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.launch(RefreshSessionImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl.processSingleEvent(RefreshQueueImpl.java:143)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.createAndFindChildWithEventFire(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:244)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.findChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualDirectoryImpl.refreshAndFindChild(VirtualDirectoryImpl.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.refreshAndFindFileByPath(VfsImplUtil.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByPath(LocalFileSystemBase.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByIoFile(LocalFileSystemBase.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil.findFileByIoFile(VfsUtil.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.IdeaSourceProvider$Gradle.getManifestFile(IdeaSourceProvider.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.getManifest(AndroidFacet.java:900)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.checkConfiguration(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:145)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.checkSettings(RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.checkSettings(RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.java:412)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl$7.fun(RunManagerImpl.java:1101)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl$7.fun(RunManagerImpl.java:1091)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$1$1$1$1.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:122)
    at com.intellij.ui.IconDeferrerImpl.evaluateDeferred(IconDeferrerImpl.java:122)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$1$1$1.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1098)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$1$1.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils$4.run(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runWithWriteActionPriority(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runWithWriteActionPriority(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:68)
    at com.intellij.ui.DeferredIconImpl$1.run(DeferredIconImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```